# Opening with default application (e.g. Skim) from helm-locate on OS X

Tags: helm, osx

I'm trying to find a way to open files in helm-locate buffers using external software in OS X. Specifically, I'd like to be able to open PDFs in Skim. I know I can hit C-u C-c C-x to choose a program to open a file with, but I can't find a way to get Skim to show up on the list that helm produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use skim as your primary pdf viewer, then set it as default application to open PDFs in OSX, then use `open` to open the file.